# Can I parameterize a pytest fixture with other fixtures?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have a python test that uses a fixture for credentials (a tuple of userid and password)

```
def test_something(credentials)
   (userid, password) = credentials
   print("Hello {0}, welcome to my test".format(userid))
```

and I have pytest fixture for credentials:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def credentials():
   return ("my_userid", "my_password")
```

It works great

Now I want to extend this for multiple credentials (say staging and production) so that my test will run twice (once each for staging and production).

I thought that parameterization was the answer, but it seems I can't parameterize with fixtures.

I would love to do something like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[staging_credentials, production_credentials])
def credentials(request):
    return request.param
```

where staging_credentials and production_credentials are all fixtures:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def staging_credentials():
   return ("staging_userid", "staging_password")

@pytest.fixture()
def production_credentials():
   return ("prod_userid", "prod_password")
```

but apparently parameters to the fixture can't be other fixtures.

Any suggestions on how to elegantly handle this?  I've looked at https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/proposals/parametrize_with_fixtures.html but that seems a but too brute force.

Thanks!
Steve

Answer (score 10):

Indirect parametrization is the answer. So, the parameters to the fixtures CAN be other fixtures (by their name/code).

```
import pytest

all_credentials = {
    'staging': ('user1', 'pass1'),
    'prod': ('user2', 'pass2'),
}

@pytest.fixture
def credentials(request):
    return all_credentials[request.param]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('credentials', ['staging', 'prod'], indirect=True)
def test_me(credentials):
    pass
```

Technically, you can not only get a dict value by its key, but generate the `credentials` result based on `request.param`, and this param will be the value passed to the same-name parameter of the test.

If you want other fixtures to be used (probably because of the setup/teardown stages, as this is the only reason to do so):

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def credentials(request):
    return request.getfuncargvalue(request.param)

@pytest.fixture()
def staging_credentials():
   return ("staging_userid", "staging_password")

@pytest.fixture()
def production_credentials():
   return ("prod_userid", "prod_password")

@pytest.mark.parametrize('credentials', ['staging_credentials', 'production_credentials'], indirect=True)
def test_me(credentials):
    pass
```

Here, `request.getfuncargvalue(...)` will return a fixture value by the fixture name, dynamically.