# Create parameterized test fixtures that depend on other parameterized test fixtures?

Tags: pytest

I want to do something like this

```
def foo_bar(a, b):
    """ The function I want to test """
    return ...

def subparams(a):
   return [some stuff based on what a is]

@pytest.fixture(scope='module', params=('foo', 'bar'))
def a(request):
    # lengthy setup based on request.param
    yield request.param
    # teardown

@pytest.fixture(params=subparams(a))
def b(request):
    return request.param

def test_foo_bar(a, b):
    result = foo_bar(a, b)
    assert <something about result>
```

In other words, I have a parameterized fixture `a` which simply takse
a normal list of parameters. For each value of `a`, I also have a function
`subparams` for generating associated parameters `b`. For the sake of argument, let's say that `subparams` is trivially implemented as follows

```
def subparams(a):
    return [1, 2, 3] if a == 'foo' else [4, 5]
```

in which case I would want `test_foo_bar` to be invoked with the following:

- `'foo', 1`
- `'foo', 2`
- `'foo', 3`
- `'bar', 4`
- `'bar', 5`

Unfortunately, the `@pytest.fixture(params=subparams(a))` bit doesn't work because at that point `a` is still just a function, not an instantiation based on `a`'s parameterization. How do I achieve the effect of having `test_foo_bar` called with those kinds of combinations of `a` and `b` where `a` takes a long time to set up (hence the `scope='module'` bit) and `b` is parameterized depending on `a`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46942231/7976758